# Conditional operator returns value from a copy of its argument

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, temporary-objects

When the two return arguments to the conditional operator `c?x:y` are not of the same type, a copy is made before the cast is applied. Can this be prevented while still keeping simple useabiltiy?

I have this (trimmed down for questions):

```
struct Fixed {
  char data[10];
  Fixed(char *s) { strcpy(data, s); }
  operator char*() { return this->data; }
};
```

But it has really bad behavior with the conditional operator and nullptr:

```
Fixed f =...; // just here to show the type of f, don't read too much into this
...
bool condition = ...;
char *s = condition ? nullptr : f;
```

A copy of f is made and s is now pointing to a value on the stack that will go away soon. This all happens because type of `nullptr` is `std::nullptr_t`. `f` will go through the cast to `char*`, but only after it is copied first. This seems like extremely poor behavior, but it is what the spec says.

My current fix is to just make the cast and ctor `explicit`, but that kind of ruins to usability a little. Are there any other solutions?

Here's some example code to play with (ignore the quality as I was heavily playing with this to see how gcc and LLVM handle this differently):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct A : public array<char,4> {
  A() { cerr<<"def\n"; }
  A(const A &o) { cerr<<"copy\n"; (*this)=o;}
  A(const char *s) { cerr<<"ctor\n";assign(s); } // explicit fixes
  void assign(const char*s) {cerr<<"assign\n";memset(this->begin(), 0, 4); strncpy(this->begin(), s, 4); }
  operator char*() { cerr<<"cast\n";return this->begin(); }
  //operator void*() { cerr<<"void\n";return this->begin(); }
  //operator std::nullptr_t() { cerr<<"void\n";return (std::nullptr_t)this->begin(); }
};

volatile A *faraway = new A();

char* plain(A &v) { cerr<<"in pl\n";
  return faraway == nullptr ? nullptr : v;
}
char* cast1(A &v) { cerr<<"in c1\n";
  return faraway == nullptr ? (char*)nullptr : v;
}
char* cast2(A &v) { cerr<<"in c2\n";
  return faraway == nullptr ? nullptr : (char*)v;
}

int main() {
  A *a = new A; a->assign("asd");

  char *x = a->data();
  cerr << "\nplain\n";
  char *yp = plain(*a);
  cerr << "\nc1\n";
  char *y1 = cast1(*a);
  cerr << "\nc2\n";
  char *y2 = cast2(*a);

  cerr << "\n---\n";
  cerr << (void*)a << "\n" << (void*)(a->data()) << "\n" << (void*)x << "\n---\n";
  cerr << (void*)yp << "\n" << (void*)y1 << "\n" << (void*)y2 << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of strage things going on here `cond?nullptr:(char*)f` works fine. `cond?(char*)nullptr:f` works fine in LLVM, but GCC refuses to compile (and I made the `Fixed(char*)` ctor explicit).

Comment: @JohnKugelman yeah, basically. I was just there to show the type of `f`. The struct is retrieved from a hash, so I'm trying to return the `char*` of the struct in the hash, instead I am returning a `char*` of a copy of the struct on the stack.

Comment: Using `somefunc(A &v)` then `&v` can not be nullptr. Please, show a better example or a better design.

Comment: @Ripi2: Surprisingly that's not true.  You can do `somefunc(*(A*)nullptr)` and it is legal as long as no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is done.

Comment: @BenVoigt Surprise to me, yes. Anyhow, I think the OP wants to use `char *x = somefunc(someinstance)` where `someinstance` is not a pointer, but a class instance.

Comment: I think the issue comes from `char* of the struct`. If you want a pointer, work with pointers. And avoid casting the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the operands of the ternary have types `std::nullptr_t` and `struct Fixed`.  The inference rule looks for conversions from one operand type to the other, as well as common base classes.  There is no opportunity to infer `char*`.

<strike>You can catch the mistake automatically, by providing `operator std::nullptr_t() = delete`;</strike>

Comment: But it does seem to infer `char*`. It even calls the correct `operator char*` method. It is just this strange need for a temporary to be created first (and also GCC's strange behavior of requiring the `Fixed(char*)` ctor but not actually using it).

Comment: @JasonN: It doesn't infer `char*`, the ternary evaluates to a `struct Fixed` temporary object.  Then the `operator char*()` is called during the initialization of the `char*` variable.  You can prove this by introducing an `auto`-typed variable in between, like `auto t = condition ? nullptr : f; cout << "Between ternary and char* initialization"; char* s = t;`

Comment: I thought ternary, had to have the same type return from both branches, in that case it would need to do the deduction before the ternary (ie, i can't return an `A`, unless if could convert from `nullptr` to `A`). ... I just tested with the `auto` and forced a compiler error to see the type. The ternary is returning an `A`, which would also imply there is an implicit convertion from `nullptr` to `A` possible? I don't understand how that is possible?

Comment: To add more ugliness to this, if the comparison is true, `nullptr` is converted to an A which segfaults with no compiler warnings. Why should it even be possible to convert nullptr_t to any non-pointer type? And with a little more playing, I can actually get the compiler admit it can convert from `nullptr_t` to `A` and /vise versa/. Ugly, but I guess not much worse than other C++ ugliness. shrug

Comment: Do you think it is a GCC bug that is needs `A(char*)` to compile, unlike LLVM, and never uses it? Should I report it?

Comment: @JasonN: `A(const char *s)` provides an implicit conversion from `nullptr_t` to `A`.  Not sure how there could be a conversion from `A` to `nullptr_t` though, unless you uncomment the corresponding conversion.

Comment: This is where LLVM and GCC start to differ. I can get LLVM to become very lenient on what the conditional produces (without the nullptr_t cast operator - although none of them seem to be wrong), while GCC takes a harder line. This is all without `-pendantic`. Thanks.